# Getting a list of all the selected elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of jQuery code which selects a long list of classes like this

```jquery
$('.class1, .class2, .someotherclass .......lots-of-classes').someEvent(function(){

});
```

Inside this code block I am doing something that applies to everything except `this`.

```jquery
$('.class1, .class2, .someotherclass .......lots-of-classes').someEvent(function(){
    $('.class1, .class2, .someotherclass .......lots-of-classes').not(this).find('a').doSomething();
});
```

How can I do this without repeating the entire list of classes? The only method I know is to assign all these classes to a variable and use it like this.

```jquery
var myclasses = '.class1, .class2, .someotherclass .......lots-of-classes';
$(myclasses).someEvent(function(){
    $(myclasses).not(this).find('a').doSomething();
});
```

Is there any way to find out what elements were used in the "parent block of code"?

Comment: What do you mean by `.someEvent()`?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It is can be any event just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store a variable to point at the original collection

```
var $myClasses = $(myclasses);
$myClasses.someEvent(function(){
    $myClasses.not(this).find('a').doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there a method to do this without variables? The reason is that I am debugging a file that belongs to an open source project. So when I submit a patch I want the number of lines to be as short as possible.

Comment: I don't think there is. It's much better to create a variable than to execute the jquery again in each callback

Comment: You're right. But I was wondering if jquery had anything similar to PHP's **Magic Constants** get information about itself :-)